# Perfect merge chronologically master and branch in Git

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a simple repository with two branches: `master` and `branch`
`branch` has been created a long time ago and commits have been accumulated on both branches.
There are two main ways to merge: `merge` and `rebase merge`.
I won't describe first case, I'm interested in second.
`rebase merge` will apply `branch` commits just after `HEAD` of `master`.
Log history is rewritten, I'm looking for a better way to merge respecting chronology.

Suppose I have this kind of repository.
`1` has been created before `2`, `2` has been created before `3` and so on...

```
  7        6
  5        4
  3        2
  1--------1
master   branch
```

I would like to perform a perfect merge respecting dates:

```
  7        7
  6        6
  5        5
  4        4
  3        3
  2        2
  1--------1
master   branch
```

I'm aware of `git rebase -i`, is there a way to perform this automatically ?
Also, I think this will create troubles in other local cloned repositories because of rewritten history.
Is there a way to safely perform this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm aware of git rebase -i, is there a way to perform this automatically ?

I don't believe there is a way to do this operation automatically, short of creating a custom script to handle the logic (probably not worth it in the long run).  `$ git rebase -i` (interactive rebase) is the way to go here.

> Also, I think this will create troubles in other local cloned repositories because of rewritten history.
>   Is there a way to safely perform this ?

If this repository and these commits are published somewhere, yes that could be a huge issue and pain for others to pull down and work through.  **The "safe" way would be to not rewrite history**.  I know that's not what you're looking for, but typically the juice is not worth the squeeze with rewriting git history, *especially* when dealing with commits that'll get pushed to remote repositories with other contributors.

Comment: Does `git rebase -i` in `branch` to reorder commits then merge onto `master` will create troubles in cloned repositories ?

Comment: @LeFlou:  Yes.  You're rewriting history, and everyone will have to reconcile what they've done against that new history, which has wide and far-reaching impacts.